# jQuery click needs clicking more than twice in IE

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, internet-explorer

This works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but not in IE and the issue is if:

```
var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);  // included in script
```

see my code:

HTML :

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input id="img_file" name="file" type="file" accept="image/x-png, image/gif, image/jpeg">
   <a href="#" id="upload" class="selective">Upload</a>
</form>
```

JS :

```
  $(document).on('click', '#upload', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'process.php',
      data: formData,
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function(formData){
        alert(formData); 
      }
    });
  });
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: not supported in IE<10 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @Daniel you must mention, which version of IE you are using, or Arun has answered your question.

Comment: you can try the jquery click event on id directly rather then click on  document, may be work for you.Any way in which version of IE you are testing the following above.

Comment: IE 10 was an issue, but I've updated to 11 and it's OK